# Scrolling in Appium using Python

Tags: python, appium, appium-android

I want to scroll down the screen, but I cannot seem to get it right. The original way with Appium is as follows:

```py
actions = TouchAction(driver)
actions.scroll_from_element(element, 10, 100)
actions.scroll(10, 100)
actions.perform()
```

And my code is:

```py
actions = TouchAction(self.driver)
actions.scroll_from_element('com.android.dialer.dialers', x=90, y=1330)
actions.scroll(x=90, y=170)
actions.perform()
```

However, I get the following error message:

```
line 133, in test_app
scroll.scroll_from_element('com.android.dialer.dialers', x=90, y=1230)
AttributeError: 'TouchAction' object has no attribute 'scroll_from_element'
```

Answer (score 5):

For me worked using the swipe function:

```
#swipe(startX, startY, endX, endY, duration)
self.driver.swipe(150, 400, 150, 200, 1000)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely getting the error because appium-python client has no `scroll_from_element` function.

The first way to scroll the screen is to find 2 element, and scroll from one to another.

```
el1 = self.driver.find_element_by_accessibility_id(<your locator to scroll from>)
el2 = self.driver.find_element_by_accessibility_id('your locator to scroll to')
action = TouchAction(self.driver)
action.press(el1).move_to(el2).release().perform()
```

If you want to move to element with offset, you can do it this way:

```
action.press(el1).move_to(el2, offsetX, offsetY).release().perform()
```

where offsetX, offsetY are representing the shift.

If your app has a scrollable view, you can scroll to required element using find+UIAutomator2 locator:

```
targetElement = self.driver.find_element_by_android_uiautomator(
            'new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true).instance(0)).scrollIntoView(new UiSelector().text("Element text").instance(0));')
```

Of course, it is better to replace `UiSelector().text("Element text")` with `uiselector().resourceid(elementId)`

I suggest checking official [functional tests](https://github.com/appium/python-client/blob/master/test/functional/android/touch_action_tests.py) in client repo as working examples